# JFrame: allow only fixed size or fullscreen JFrame

Tags: swing, resize, jframe

I was developing fixed-size Swing application, but now I need to allow user to switch to fullscreen mode. I don't want to allow custom resizing of JFrame for not refactoring all components' sizes and staff - only fullscreen. So that in fullscreen mode I'll need to resize 1 jTabbedPane and move few other components.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) that allows for resizing.

Otherwise, you add a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to the JFrame.  Write the `componentResized` method so that any attempt to resize the JFrame resets the original size.

Unless your audience for this application is limited, different users have different full screen sizes.